# Scala create instance with Class which accepts duck typing parameter

Tags: scala, reflection, duck-typing

I have following class:

```
class Test(env: {val configConsumner: ConfigurationConsumer})
```

And I have `val classInstance: Class[A]` object. I want to instantiate this class instance with parameter indicated in the ducktype above. How do I do this in Scala.

In Java you could get constructor with the dependency. Then instantiate that constructor with the parameter using reflection.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused by what you are asking.  Does the type `A` have a constructor on it that takes an instance defined by the duck typed example `env` in the `Test` class?  Put another way, does the constructor for `A` match that of `Test`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the type's constructor has no arguments you can do:

```
def createTest[A <: {val configConsumner: ConfigurationConsumer}](c: Class[A]): Test = new Test(c.newInstance())
```

if the constructor does have arguments you can use:

```
def createTest[A <: {val configConsumner: ConfigurationConsumer}](c: Class[A], args: Any*): Test = {
    val constructor = c.getConstructor(args.map(_.getClass) : _*)
    val inst = constructor.newInstance(args.toArray : _*)
    new Test(inst)
}
```